# Codeigniter batch insert performance

Tags: mysql, performance, codeigniter

Does `$this->db->insert_batch();` insert with 1 table connection or does it insert each row separately incurring overhead of opening connections?

Comment: Database Connection should be always one, whether batch or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the documentation of code igniter `insert_batch` do this kind of things

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name' ,
      'date' => 'My date'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name' ,
      'date' => 'Another date'
   )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data); 

// Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date'), ('Another title', 'Another name', 'Another date')
```

So it would produce only one query with all the values, normally this way faster then doing separate inserts.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question: It uses one connection.

Answer (score 1):

Actually @RageZ answer based on document is not always correct. Because it's totally based on the number of items you want to insert. When looking at codeigniter `insert_batch()` code, you can see that they slice batch inserts into 100 items.

```
// Batch this baby (Around line number 1077 in codeigniter 2.x)
for ($i = 0, $total = count($this->ar_set); $i < $total; $i = $i + 100)
{
    $sql = $this->_insert_batch($this->_protect_identifiers($table, TRUE, NULL, FALSE), $this->ar_keys, array_slice($this->ar_set, $i, 100));

    //echo $sql;

    $this->query($sql);
}
```

It means that your values will be slice to 100s inserts and if you uncomment the `echo $sql` part you can see what it's look like when you use insert batch for 101 items. So based on your connection preferences there can be more than one connection needed for inserting in db.

Comment: @Ragez's answer may have been true when this question was asked, I think I was using CI 1.xx

Comment: @amiawizard That can be right and the only way to ensure is to look at the code. As I know they haven't changed documents of this part from 1.x but it's possible that code had changed from 1.x to 2.x

Comment: @amiawizard I checked 1.7.1 and 1.7.3 and there is no insert_batch function in them and it seems that this function introduced in version 2.x https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/user_guide_src/source/changelog.rst